# Symfony 2 - Creating and persisting json-Object from Form Data. Use Entities and FormTypes?

Tags: json, symfony

I am working on a reporting tool using the Symfony 2 framework. This reporting tool uses a lot of parameters that are passed through an html form filled out by the user. The Parameters are then used to create a report. We are talking about 40 to 50 parameters.

My idea: 
Instead of creating for each paramter an database column, my idea is to create a json object containing all data and persist it in one database field. I have worked out some possible solutions. May be you can give me some advise about which one is the advantageous.

Solution 1: I could create an Entity and a Formtype (like the common way in Symfony 2) and instead of persisting the Entity-Object into Database I would serialize the whole Object then persist it in a single Database-Field.

```
     $report = new Report();
     $form = $this->createForm(new ReportType(), $report);


    if ($form->isValid()) {

           $reportSerialized = serialize($reportParams);
           //...then persist $reportSerialized
```

Then when creating the Report I would unserialize the object:

```
//...load report from database
$reportParams = unserialize($reportSerialized);
```

I tried this method, but had problems with unserializing when there were nested objects.

Solution 2: I do not use neither an Doctrine Entity nor a Formtype Entity but get the data directly from the request as an array and create an json object from that array and persist it.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

       $reportParams = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
       $reportParams = serialize($reportParams);
       //...then persist into Database
```

Then when creating the Report I would unserialize the object:

```
$reportParams = unserialize($reportSerialized);
```

Which of these two solution is the best practice, or have you a complete different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using doctrine have a look at [simple array](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#simple-array) or [array](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#array) types.

Maps and converts array data based on PHP serialization. If you need to store an exact representation of your array data, you should consider using this type as it uses serialization to represent an exact copy of your array as string in the database. Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP’s array type using deserialization or null if no data is present.

The annotation for that is:

```
/**
 * @var YourType[]
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
```

Comment: What do you think about my second solution that works without an doctrine entity and catches directly the data from the form in controller. –